# MVC 5 DI with Web API 2 DI--how should dependency registrations be structured?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection

I'm creating an MVC 5 site with Web API 2 functionality inside it as well and I'm wondering how I should work with the fact that ASP.NET uses 2 different resolver instances for resolving MVC controllers and ApiControllers.

I found [this article](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/using-unity.mvc5-and-unity.webapi-together-in-a-project) that explains how to configure the resolution, but it looks like it uses 2 separate container instances and doesn't explain how to register dependencies for each. It's just like "do your registration here."

Following the 2-container example, I was tempted to set up the app so that the Web API container only has Web API dependencies and the MVC container only has mvc controller dependencies, but I feel like in the situation where a component is used for both, having a subset of items used in both containers would be too much work to maintain correctly.

Is it okay to just have all of the dependencies installed in each container? Or is it better to use the same container in each resolver?

Edit: I'm not using Unity so I'm writing a resolver class to wrap Windsor. I'm considering having my resolver implement both interfaces and just assigning the same instance as the different resolvers as well.

Comment: The solution in the attached article doesn't involve two container instances. I wonder what made you think so. They have a single container and two resolvers around it.

Comment: You're right--I don't know how I missed that. I'll answer my question then!

Comment: A good library for this is http://www.ninject.org/